# How to create type of array with different object types

Tags: node.js, reactjs, angular, typescript

type structure is
example:

```
type TFiltersTypes = 'selectableTags' | 'dropdown';

type TSelectableTabsFilterItem = {
    id: string;
    label: string;
    isSelected: boolean;
};

type TFilter = {
    type: TFiltersTypes;
    label: TLocalesKey;
    data: (TFiltersTypes extends 'selectableTags'
        ? TSelectableTabsFilterItem
        : TDropdownFilterItem)[];
};

type TDropdownFilterItem = {
    id: string;
    label: string;
    Icon: string;
    isSelected: boolean;
};

type TFilterProps = {
    data: TFilter[];
};

const data = [
    {
        type: 'selectableTags',
        label: 'filters.mediaType.label',
// Property 'Icon' is missing in type '{ id: string; label: string; isSelected: true; }' but required 
// in type 'TDropdownFilterItem'.(2741)
// TSelectableTabsFilterItem
        data: [
            {
                id: '1',
                label: '12',
                isSelected: true,
            },
            {
                id: '2',
                label: '1',
                isSelected: false,
            },
            {
                id: '3',
                label: '1',
                isSelected: false,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        type: 'dropdown',
        label: 'filters.services.label',
        data: [
// TDropdownFilterItem 
            {
                id: '1',
                label: '1',
                Icon: '',
                isSelected: true,
            },
        ],
    },
] satisfies TFilter[];
```

Right now I have an error
`Property 'Icon' is missing in type '{ id: string; label: string; isSelected: true; }' but required in type 'TDropdownFilterItem'.`  Is it possible to create something that works?  I expect to have flexible type for array with different object types depending on object id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `TFilter` to be a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) where each union member has a distinct pairing of `type`/`data` property types. Like this:

```
type TFilter = {
    type: 'selectableTags',
    label: string,
    data: TSelectableTabsFilterItem[]
} | {
    type: 'dropdown';
    label: string;
    data: TDropdownFilterItem[];
};
```

The example code doesn't work because `TFiltersTypes` is just a specific type, and so the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) `TFiltersTypes extends 'selectableTags' ? TSelectableTabsFilterItem : TDropdownFilterItem` is evaluated eagerly to just  `TDropdownFilterItem`.  If `TFiltersTypes` were a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter then you would be able to use a conditional type to switch on it like that, but it still wouldn't be useful since then `TFilter` would need to be a generic type like `TFilter<T extends TFiltersTypes>`.  The best case scenario there would end up producing a discriminated union anyway, so that's what you should do from the start.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.2.2#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-YslbpkDmt2OLbcHt5-IFpDQADcEBRcJK1tPsS1cVBrXHdTADgtjvjTVBeyPLw7q5nr7TZxmt36AUC8s+3W3A+FQz2U8OOUHFYyxGOwWkCPlcFSZELiAA)